# My GetBetween function need to get multiple results

Tags: php

I have been using this function to get content between tags, because its faster than **preg_match_all** (almost 100 queries once).

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}

$content = ",john,,benny,,steven,gerard,";
$usercount = substr_count($content,",") / 2;

for ($t=0;$t<$usercount;$t++)
{  

$users = GetBetween($content,",",",");
echo $users

}
```

However, it just gives me one result. Which method should I use to get all results ?

Comment: if you want to get a quick help - show the input data and the expected result

Comment: `GetBetween` function has a strange and overcomplicated logic. What for? You just want to get all words between commas, right?

Comment: Correct, so is there better option(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get all words between commas(as separators) use the following simple approach with `explode` and `array_filter` functions:

```
$content = ",john,,benny,,steven,gerard,";
$words = array_filter(explode(",", $content));
// now you can easily iterate through $words array outputting each word
print_r($words);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => john
    [3] => benny
    [5] => steven
    [6] => gerard
)
```